# Is there any way to show copy-paste toolbar initially without long pressed or double click on text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, text, copy-paste

I am building a Flutter application that captures text from image. Now what I need is to have selectable text with cursor on both ends. i.e start and end while selecting whole text initially for copy purpose.

I created a 'textformfield'. Here is the source code:

```java
controller = TextEditingController(
  text: initialValu,
);
controller.selection = new TextSelection(
  baseOffset: 0,
  extentOffset: controller.value.text.length,
);
TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      autofocus: true,
      maxLines: 1000,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none
      ),
      enableInteractiveSelection: true,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  showCursor: true,

    )
```

I used the above code but it did not show the copy-paste toolbar initially. I would like to show as the above photo.